# MySQL PHP doesnt update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help with my php Code which is supposed to update my mysql database. I tried it this way:

```
<?php mysql_connect("servername","name","passwort"); 
mysql_select_db("dbname"); 
$name = $_GET["name"]; $points = $_GET["points"]; 
$query = "UPDATE highscore SET points=".$points." WHERE name='".$name."'";

mysql_query($query) 
mysql_close(); ?>
```

I called it with:

```
http://.../write.php?name=%22Alexa%20Bomkamp%22&points=%22100
```

But literally nothing happened. No error, but also no update.
Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: can you do `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: What a lovely SQL injection opportunity ;)

Comment: note: you shouldn't use the $_GET parameters directly in your sql statement, that makes the whole script vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: wait you're missing a semi-colon in `mysql_query($query)`

Comment: just echo `$query` and check the SQL statement

Comment: How is your PHP environment set up? Is display_errors set to true?

Comment: I dont even know what sql injection is. This is the first time that im using sql...  may someone can explain me sql iniection?

Comment: it's in different places on the internet, search for it.

Comment: try to check if php settings `display errors` is enabled in your server also. you might have an error in your code.

Comment: The semicolon is just a spelling error

Comment: [Who is Bobby Tables?](http://www.bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url is wrong **%22** takes **"** htmlentity avoid it and number contains also **%22**

call with this url: 
   .../write.php?name=Alexa%20Bomkamp&points=100

Answer (score 1):

First, you should check that `$_GET` gets the parameters you call the script with. A `print_r($_GET);` is sufficient for this.

Secondly, your code looks horrid. You are missing linebreaks, and all. What is more terrifying, that you are **totally vulnearable** to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). **NEVER** let the SQL execute a command which contains unescaped and unchecked user input. With a little addition to the parameters, you could easily lose your database.

The other thing is, that judging from your code, you are using a bad practice. What if I enter a name which is new to the database. In that case, the `UPDATE` statement will fail, you will need to use `INSERT INTO` instead.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect( 'servername', 'loginname', 'password' ) or die('Unable to connect.');
mysql_select_db( 'database', $link ) or die('Unable to select database.');

$query = 'UPDATE `highscore` SET `points`=' .mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['points']). ' WHERE `name`="' .mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']). '";';
mysql_query( $query, $link );
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Also, you have an unneeded `%22` in your request. Call the code with `?name=Alexa Bompkamp&points=100`.

Comment: Tnaks for the help. But i get an error wth your code :(

    Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escpae_string() in /home/www/cwcity/hosting/b/i/bitchapp/htdocs/write.php on line 5

Comment: Oh. I made a typo. It's `mysql_real_escape_string` not _escpae_. I have updated the answer too.

Comment: doesnt work either. no error, but no change in the DB. is it possible that the database blocks updates or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("servername","name","passwort"); 
mysql_select_db("dbname");
if (mysql_error()) {
    echo "<br />". mysql_errno(). " : ". mysql_error();
}
$name = $_GET["name"]; $points = $_GET["points"]; 
$query = "UPDATE highscore SET points=$points WHERE name='$name'";

mysql_query($query, $conn);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are encoding the parameters while sending the request then please decode it. One more thing please use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for avoiding SQL injection while assigning `get` values to your parameters